# How can I make a file selector with a combobox in VC++ 2008?

Tags: c++, visual-studio, controls, combobox

I have this dialog:

> ID__BATERIA __FAX DIALOGEX 0, 0, 235, 86
>
> STYLE DS_SETFONT | DS_MODALFRAME | DS_FIXEDSYS | WS_POPUP | WS_CAPTION |  WS_SYSMENU

CAPTION "Nueva batería de fax" FONT 8, "MS Shell Dlg", 400, 0, 0x1

BEGIN

> ```
> DEFPUSHBUTTON   "OK",IDOK,120,65,50,14
> PUSHBUTTON      "Cancel",IDCANCEL,175,65,50,14
> LTEXT           "Archivo",IDC_STATIC,20,12,25,8
> LTEXT           "Descripción",IDC_STATIC,20,40,37,8
> EDITTEXT        IDC_DESCBATER,65,38,120,13,ES_AUTOHSCROLL 
> COMBOBOX        IDC_ARCH2,65,10,120,60,CBS_DROPDOWN | CBS_AUTOHSCROLL | CBS_SORT | WS_VSCROLL | WS_TABSTOP
> ```

END

I want the combobox to be a file selector. So I wrote this:

BOOL CALLBACK BateriaFaxDlg(HWND hDlg, UINT msg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam){

```
char descripcion[100];
char archivo[20];

switch (msg)                  /* manipulador del mensaje */
{
    case WM_INITDIALOG:
        SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_ARCH2), CB_DIR, DDL_READWRITE | DDL_DIRECTORY, (LPARAM)"*");       
        return TRUE;
    case WM_COMMAND:
        switch (LOWORD(wParam)) {
        case IDOK:
            SendDlgItemMessage(hDlg, IDC_ARCH2, WM_GETTEXT, 20, (LPARAM)archivo);
            GetDlgItemText(hDlg, IDC_DESCBATER, descripcion , 100);
            actualizarBaterias("FAX", archivo, descripcion);
            EndDialog(hDlg, FALSE);
            break;
        case IDCANCEL:
            EndDialog(hDlg, FALSE);
            break;
        case IDC_ARCH2:             
            switch(HIWORD(wParam)) {
        case CBN_DBLCLK:
                   if(DlgDirSelectEx(hDlg, archivo, 512, IDC_ARCH2)) {                        
                      // DlgDirList(hDlg, "*", IDC_ARCH2, ID_TITULO, DDL_DIRECTORY | DDL_DRIVES);   
                       SendMessage(GetDlgItem(hDlg, IDC_ARCH2), CB_DIR, 0, (LPARAM)"*");
                    // IniciarLista(hwnd, cad);
                  } 
                break;
            }
            break;
        default:
            break;           
       return TRUE;
        }
}
return FALSE;
```

}

It shows correctly the files and the directorys, but when I try to enter a directory it won't work. The thing I select is [dir] instead going inside and showing the files.

Can anyone help me?

Thanks a lot.

UPDATE:

Ok, I changed it and now it is a Simple ComboBox. Still when I double click on the directories it won't enter and list the files inside. Any ideas?

UPDATE:

It finally works.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb775808.aspx

"This notification message occurs only for a combo box with the CBS_SIMPLE style. In a combo box with the CBS_DROPDOWN or CBS_DROPDOWNLIST style, a double-click cannot occur because a single click closes the list box."

Comment: Thanks a lot, I haven't noticed about that. When I selected the type of Combobox I was thinking only in it being small.